# How to aggregate boolean values in elastic search?

Tags: highcharts, elasticsearch

I am having several experiments a day storing the **error** of the experiment and a **boolean** value (if the result is ok) in elasticsearch.
Now, I would like to display the results in a graph (using highchart js).
I use an aggregation query like this to receive the aggregated errors for each day including the standard deviation:

```
query: {
                    filtered: {
                        filter: {
                            range : {
                                date: {
                                    "gte":"2015-1-1",
                                    "lte": "2016-1-1,
                                    "time_zone": "+1:00"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                // Aggregate on the results
                aggs: {
                    group_by_date: {
                        terms:{
                            field:"date",
                            order: {_term:"asc"}
                        }, 
                        aggs:{
                            error_stats:{
                                extended_stats:{
                                    field:"error"
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The problem I face is that I cannot retrieve the boolean values the same way as I get the double errors from the DB.
When I just change the field name to "ok" in

```
aggs:{
                            error_stats:{
                                extended_stats:{
                                    field:"ok"
                                } 
                            }
                        }
```

I receive this error message:

```
ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData
```

However, it would be OK to aggreate all the boolean values usign true as 1 and false as zero and then to receive a mean value for each day.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks alot!

Comment: For the highcharts you need to parse your data into correct format. I mean data should be array of objects with x/y values. Dates should be timestamps (time in miliseconds).

Comment: thats correct. but the problem already appears in the query. highchart does not start yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First 0/1 representation is not exactly ES Boolean representation. There is a Boolean type for as true/false.
Second stats aggregation can be only done on numeric field and not on string field. 
That is why it worked for 0/1 representation.

You can transform this value using [scripts in extended stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-extendedstats-aggregation.html#_value_script_6)

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        ...

        "aggs" : {
            "grades_stats" : {
                "extended_stats" : {
                    "field" : "grade",
                    "script" : "_value == 'T' ? 1 : 0",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To see some example usage of scripting in aggregation , you can look [here](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-scripting-aggregations).

Comment: thank you! Ok, but is there a possibility to overcome this? Maybe by using scripts in the query? However, I am new to this and would appreciate any example.

Comment: Using a script in an 'agg' on millions of millions of records is not a feasible solution