# Elasticsearch filter the maximum value document

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I trying to get the maximum value of document from the same name records. Forexample, I have 3 users, 2 of them have same name but different followers count, I wanted to return only 1 document from the 2 same with same name based on the maximum of followers_count.

```
{ id: 1, name: "John Greenwood", follower_count: 100 }
{ id: 2, name: "John Greenwood", follower_count: 200 }
{ id: 3, name: "John Underwood", follower_count: 300 }
```

So the result would be,

```
{ id: 2, name: "John Greenwood", follower_count: 200 }
{ id: 3, name: "John Underwood", follower_count: 300 }
```

From 2 same names, the one with the maximum followers wins and other single one will also come.

I have mapping as follow,

```
"users-development" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "user" : {
        "dynamic" : "false",
        "properties" : {
          "follower_count" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "exact" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
```

This is where I have been stucked from long,

```
         {
            query: {
              filtered: {
                filter: {
                  bool: {
                    must: [
                      { terms: { "name.exact": [ "John Greenwood", "John Underwood" ] } },
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },

            aggs: {
              max_follower_count: { max: { field: 'follower_count' } }
            },

            size: 1000,
          }
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: this is the only thing I've had time to find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449703/elasticsearch-group-by-multiple-fields#18450596 will try to post back again with more specifics

Comment: Is that the full query? Do you get any error messages? Your trailing comma there at the end of `size:1000,` would cause an issue.

I ran the query with your data, and did not have a problem otherwise.

Comment: @IanGabes no I don't get any error messages I am working in ruby

Answer (score 3):

Your question have a special tool in the elastic stack as a hammer for a head kkk.
Are [Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html), See the examples:
First of all in your case you will need aggregate by full name including spaces, your name field need to be [not_analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) like this

```
`PUT /index
{
  "mappings": {
    "users" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" :    "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Now your query will be like this one:

```
`POST /index/users/_search
{
   "aggs": {
      "users": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "name"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "followers": {
               "max": {
                  "field": "follower_count"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}`
```

I just aggregated by name and used a max [metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics.html) to get the higgest follower count.

The response will be like this:

```
`"aggregations": {
      "users": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "John Greenwood",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "followers": {
                  "value": 200
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "John Underwood",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "followers": {
                  "value": 300
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }`
```

Hope that will be good for you.
Use aggregations for all situations that you need aggregate data and get sum on values.

Comment: awesome seems like a good solution, What if I have another field where I wanted to give preference one true on false and if that preference is applied I don't wanted to apply the aggregation. Thoughts

Comment: @MuhamamdAwais probably this is the awnser of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050292/how-to-aggregate-boolean-values-in-elastic-search

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you are looking for something along these lines, using the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

```
{
   "query": {
      "terms": { "name.exact": [ "John Greenwood", "John Underwood" ] }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "max_follower_count": {
         "terms": {
            "field":"name.exact"
         },
         "aggs":{
             "max_follow" : { "max" : { "field" : "follower_count" } }
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 1000
}
```

The terms aggregation will make a bucket for each unique value, from `names.exact`, which will only be those specified in your terms query. So we now have a bucket for both Johns, now we can use the `max` aggregation to count who has the most followers. The `max` aggregation will operate on each bucket in its parent aggregation.

Each of these unique terms will then have its max value of `follower_count` computed, and displayed in the bucket. Results look as follows:

```
... //query results of just the terms query up here
"aggregations": {
  "max_follower_count": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "John Greenwood",
           "doc_count": 2,
           "max_follow": {
              "value": 200
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "John Underwood",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "max_follow": {
              "value": 300
           }
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

The terms aggregation comes with a few caveats with how it does the counting, and the documentation linked should be pretty clear on that.